# Dumping an unknown object in Java WITHOUT toString()

Tags: java, tcp, tostring

My Java suite streams objects over TCP/IP using ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream.

Occasionally the receiver gets an unknown object from the sender.  For example (removing all the Exception catching and consistency tests):

```
  ObjectInputStream sInput = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());  
  while (true) {
        Object receivedObject = sInput.readObject();
        System.out.println("Received object class: " + 
                 receivedObject.getClass().getSimpleName() + 
                 "\nValue: [" + receivedObject.toString() + "]");
 }
```

I will occasionally get output like this:

```
Received object class: Object
Value: [java.lang.Object@12345678]
```

Is there a way to dump the object?  I mean, *really* dump the object.  Not override toString(). (Every object I send has its toString() method properly defined.)

It seems like something gets mixed up in the transfer over the wire, so the receiving Java VM cannot tell me what the object was.

My first thought was that the client and the server had mis-matched Java classes.  (This *could* be a problem that would lead to this output.)  But I eliminated this possibility by running the client and the server from the exact same class files (same disk, same folders, etc.).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you get there is an actual instance of java.lang.Object. There is nothing to dump.

Comment: Reflection? If you're getting just a plain Object class, though, I don't see that doing much good

Comment: JSON? Some JSON libraries can read a whole object using reflection.

Comment: Your object should implement Serializable interface.

Comment: I see some of the problem.  My basic assumption that something got corrupted in the stream is not right (at least not at this time).  As JB pointed out, what I am seeing is just an Object object.